# Doctrine fail to flush user

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42P01]:
> Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "user" does not exist LINE 1:
> INSERT INTO "user" (id, username, roles, password, name, sur...
> my migration

```php
final class Version20220424131922 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE "user" (id UUID NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, surname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, birthday DATE NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, gender VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, is_verified BOOLEAN NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_email ON "user" (email)');
        $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_username ON "user" (username)');
        $this->addSql('COMMENT ON COLUMN "user".id IS \'(DC2Type:uuid)\'');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE verify_user_request (id UUID NOT NULL, user_id UUID NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_7AD17FBAA76ED395 ON verify_user_request (user_id)');
        $this->addSql('COMMENT ON COLUMN verify_user_request.id IS \'(DC2Type:uuid)\'');
        $this->addSql('COMMENT ON COLUMN verify_user_request.user_id IS \'(DC2Type:uuid)\'');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE verify_user_request ADD CONSTRAINT FK_7AD17FBAA76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA public');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE verify_user_request DROP CONSTRAINT FK_7AD17FBAA76ED395');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE "user"');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE verify_user_request');
    }
}
```

method that cause this error:

```php
    public function register(Request $request): Response
    {
        $data = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($request);
        $this->validator->validateSchema('/../Schemas/register.json', (object)$data);
        $user = new User($data["username"], $data["name"], $data["surname"], $data["gender"], new DateTime($data["birthday"]), $data["email"] );
        $hashedPassword = $this->userPasswordHasher->hashPassword($user, $data['password']);
        $user->setPassword($hashedPassword);
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
        $event = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new UserCreateEvent($user, new JsonResponse([], 201)), UserCreateEvent::NAME);
        return $event->getResponse();
    }
```

I have all migrations applied to the postgres database and i can see them in dbeaver.
I tried to check differences between my entities and db using:

```sh
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate
```

but it did nothing.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think that the problem could be `"user" ` in your migration it is the only table in double quote. Probably that's because user is a reserved word in Postgress (not sure). Try to change it in `users` or something else without quotes

Comment: but it worked ealier. It broke after adding ValidateUserRequest to database

Comment: Even if I change the table name with user to user_account, it still doesn't work.